# remove duplicate characters from a string

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringWithoutDuplicate {

    public static void stringWithoutDuplicate(String s1)
    {
        int n = s1.length();
        int i = 0;
        while(i<n)
        {
            if(s1.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(i+1))
            {
                if(s1.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(n-1))
                {
                    System.out.println(s1.charAt(i));
                }
                i++;
            }
            else if(s1.charAt(i) != s1.charAt(i+1))
            {
                if(s1.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(n-1))
                {
                    System.out.println(s1.charAt(i));
                }
                 System.out.println(s1.charAt(i));;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s =  new Scanner(System.in);
        s.useDelimiter(",");
        String s1 = s.next();

        System.out.println(s1);

        stringWithoutDuplicate(s1);

    }
}
```

The code is giving the output but with an exception
please tell me the error in my code and ways to correct it.
I don't want to change the logic of my code so kindly solve it using this logic only.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: The error you're getting is because of s1.charAt(i + 1).  At some point, i + 1 will exceed the length of s1.

Answer (score 0):

**ERROR:**

Range of your `i` is from `0 to (n-1)` which is same as the range of index of characters in your string `s1`. This is correct.

But during the last iteration of your `while loop`, `i = n-1`

At this point, `s1.charAt(i+1)` becomes same as `s1.charAt(n)`. This should be giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void stringWithoutDuplicate(String s1) {
    int prev = -1;
    for (int i = 0, size = s1.length(); i < size; ++i) {
        char c = s1.charAt(i);
        if (c != prev) {
            System.out.println(c);
            prev = c;
        }
    }
}
```